# list-packages hangs when contacting melpa

Tags: package, package-repositories, list-packages

I'm running Emacs 26.3 on Linux Mint 20. I am using paradox, but this also happens when I use the vanilla Emacs packages interface.

When I call `list-packages`, the Paradox Menu section of the mode line just says "Loading', and the little progress indicator keeps going, but it never completes. I have a bunch of different package archives enabled, but I commented them all out and re-enabled them one by one, and it's only melpa that causes the problem. Even melpa-stable works.

Anybody encountered this? Any troubleshooting steps to try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out two minutes after posting.

In case it helps somebody else, the problem was that I had an outdated URL for the melpa package archive in my `init.el`. Perhaps there had been a redirect in place that caused it to function up until recently.

For posterity, the correct value was available here: [Melpa: Getting Started](https://melpa.org/#/getting-started).
As of July 2020, it was `https://melpa.org/packages/`. (For the curious, I had `http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/`.)

Comment: For me, I had the new address but was using HTTP. Seems to be disabled now.